# CodeIgniter site_url doesn't work with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm on codeigniter and I can't link the pages using site_url on navbar like

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('portofolio'); ?>">Portofolio</a>
```

and its work when I call it with index.php on the url. 

 below is my directory :

```
- portofolio
--- application
----- controller
----- model
----- view
----- .htaccess
--- css
--- script
```

and this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|script)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

please help me find out which block of code that's wrong

Comment: This `.htaccess` is in your root directory? Do you have set the `base_url` in your config file? If yes, enter to this directory in your server `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and find `AllowOverride` and set it to `All`

Comment: @elddenmedio Thanks for your answer, I just forgot to move the .htaccess to my root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @elddenmedio. The problem is the directory of the .htaccess file is not on the root directory. It works when its moved to the root directory.